# Is it possible to create a unique pivot table for each page of a QGIS Atlas?

Tags: qgis, atlas, pivot-table

I have a shapefile of city points and a LibreOffice spreadsheet of daily information about each city. The data is fine, I successfully built a pivot table in LibreOffice that sums city data over a two week period and joined that pivot table to the city point file via the common 'cityid' column. And the map in the QGIS layout is looking good.

When new daily tabular data comes in, I add it to the LibreOffice spreadsheet, refresh the pivot table in LibreOffice and then refresh the QGIS map. So far, so good. But if I want to look at the data from a month ago in QGIS, I have to go back to LibreOffice, edit the range of dates in the pivot table and refresh QGIS. I *could* create a unique pivot table and join layer for each day, but I'd like to avoid doing that if possible.

My question is, is it possible to use the Altas feature of QGIS to create a unique pivot table (or expression to the same effect) for each page? For example, Page 1 would show a map with the data from Jan 1 - Jan 14, Page 2 would show a map with the data from Jan 2 - Jan 15, and so on. I've used basic Atlas functions before but haven't had luck getting this to work, or finding another elegant solution.

Comment: what do you mean to use a 'SQL' statement? When I do this, I use postgresql/postgis to create a pivot with all values I might need, and use the print layout table with an expression to only show features the atlas is showing.

Comment: Whoops, I should have said expression. So maybe I'll have to do the same two-step process you use, first a pivot table in postgresql/postgis and then the Atlas expression.

Comment: Oh if you have Postgresql you're set! Let me know if you have any issues, but we've done similar work so it does work!